# iterator Overload Member Selection vs Indirection Operator

Tags: c++, iterator, operators, member, indirection

So in the interest of creating a [Minimal. Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I have created a toy `iterator` here (I know it's not perfect, it's just for the purposes of asking a question):

```
class foo : public iterator<input_iterator_tag, string> {
    string _foo;
    static const size_t _size = 13;
public:
    const string& operator*() { return _foo; }
    const foo& operator++() {
        _foo += '*';
        return *this;
    }
    const foo operator++(int) { 
        auto result = *this;
        _foo += '*';
        return result;
    }
    bool operator==(const foo& rhs) { return _foo.empty() != rhs._foo.empty() && _foo.size() % _size == rhs._foo.size() % _size; }
    bool operator!=(const foo& rhs) { return !operator==(rhs); }
};
```

I read that an [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) needs to have defined the Member Selection Operator. The Indirection Operator makes sense, but a Member Selection Operator is confusing to me here. How would an Member Selection Operator be implemented for `foo`?

Comment: By the way, the prefix ++ operator should return `foo&` instead of `const foo&` or you won't be able to do `++(++i)` - and it's missing the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const string* operator->() const { return &_foo; }
```

Example usage:

```
foo i;
++i;
assert(i->length() == 1);
```

The way this works is that the compiler will generate repeated calls to `operator->` until the return type is a raw pointer (so in this case just one call to `foo::operator->`), then do the regular member selection operation on that pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The `operator->()` should return a pointer type of the type the container holds that the iterator is used on.  So if you have a container that holds a `std::string` then the `iterator::operator->` should return a `std::sting*`.  In your case since you derive from [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) you can use the `pointer` typedef for the return type.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I was not sure if that was a mistake by the OP or not.  They use `std::string` for the template parameter to `iterator` which makes `iterator::pointer` a `std::string*` and I believe the class should actually store the data member as `pointer _foo;`.