# Validity of pointer returned by operator->

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, unique-ptr

I'm implementing a two-dimensional array container (like `boost::multi_array<T,2>`, mostly for practice). In order to use double-index notation (`a[i][j]`), I introduced a proxy class `row_view` (and `const_row_view` but I'm not concerned about constness here) which keeps a pointer to the beginning and end of the row.

I would also like to be able to iterate over rows and over elements within a row separately:

```
matrix<double> m;
// fill m
for (row_view row : m) {
    for (double& elem : row) {
        // do something with elem
    }
}
```

Now, the `matrix<T>::iterator` class (which is meant to iterate over rows) keeps a private `row_view rv;` internally to keep track of the row the iterator is pointing to. Naturally, `iterator` also implements dereferenciation functions:

- for `operator*()`, one would usually want to return a reference. Instead, here the right thing to do seems to return a `row_view` by value (i.e. return a copy of the private `row_view`). This ensures that when the iterator is advanced, the `row_view` still points to the previous row. (In a way, `row_view` acts like a reference would).
- for `operator->()`, I'm not so sure. I see two options:

  1. Return a pointer to the private `row_view` of the iterator:

     ```
     row_view* operator->() const { return &rv; }
     ```
  2. Return a pointer to a new `row_view` (a copy of the private one). Because of storage lifetime, that would have to be allocated on the heap. In order to ensure clean-up, I'd wrap it in a `unique_ptr`:

     ```
     std::unique_ptr<row_view> operator->() const {
         return std::unique_ptr<row_view>(new row_view(rv));
     }
     ```

Obviously, 2 is more correct. If the iterator is advanced *after* `operator->` is called, the `row_view` that is pointed to in 1 will change. However, the only way I can think of where this would matter, is if the `operator->` was called by its full name and the returned pointer was bound:

```
matrix<double>::iterator it = m.begin();
row_view* row_ptr = it.operator->();
// row_ptr points to view to first row
++it;
// in version 1: row_ptr points to second row (unintended)
// in version 2: row_ptr still points to first row (intended)
```

However, this is not how you'd typically use `operator->`. In such a use case, you'd probably call `operator*` and keep a reference to the first row. Usually, one would immediately use the pointer to call a member function of `row_view` or access a member, e.g. `it->sum()`.

My question now is this: Given that the `->` syntax suggests immediate use, is the validity of the pointer returned by `operator->` considered to be limited to that situation, or would a *safe* implementation account for the above "abuse"?

Obviously, solution 2 is way more expensive, as it requires heap-allocation. This is of course very much undesirable, as dereferenciation is quite a common task and there is no real need for it: using `operator*` instead avoids these problems as it returns a stack-allocated copy of the `row_view`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to return a reference for `operator *` and a pointer for `operator ->`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191290/iterator-overload-member-selection-vs-indirection-operator

Comment: According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators): "The overload of operator -> must either return a raw pointer or return an object (by reference or by value), for which operator -> is in turn overloaded."

Comment: As for `operator*`, I didn't find any restrictions. The compiler sure doesn't complain.

Comment: It wont complain but standard expectation is to get a reference to the element the container contains.

Comment: I think the `row_view` sort of acts as a "smart reference". I agree that one should abuse operator overloading counter to users' expectations but in this case it seems to cater the user's expectations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, `operator->` is applied recursively on the functions return type until a raw pointer is encountered. The only exception is when it's called by name like in your code sample.

You can use that to your advantage and return a custom proxy object. To avoid the scenario in your last code snippet, this object needs to satisfy several requirements:

1. Its type name should be private to the `matrix<>::iterator`, so outside code could not refer to it.
2. Its construction/copy/assignment should be private. `matrix<>::iterator` will have access to those by virtue of being a friend.

An implementation will look somewhat like this:

```
template <...>
class matrix<...>::iterator {
private:
  class row_proxy {
    row_view *rv_;
    friend class iterator;
    row_proxy(row_view *rv) : rv_(rv) {}
    row_proxy(row_proxy const&) = default;
    row_proxy& operator=(row_proxy const&) = default;
  public:
    row_view* operator->() { return rv_; }
  };
public:
  row_proxy operator->() {
    row_proxy ret(/*some row view*/);
    return ret;
  }
};
```

The implementation of `operator->` returns a named object to avoid any loopholes due to guaranteed copy elision in C++17. Code that use the operator inline (`it->mem`) will work as before. However, any attempt to call `operator->()` by name without discarding the return value, will not compile.

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbd4fdba79d7bb9b)</kbd>

```
struct data {
    int a;
    int b;
} stat;

class iterator {
    private:
      class proxy {
        data *d_;
        friend class iterator;
        proxy(data *d) : d_(d) {}
        proxy(proxy const&) = default;
        proxy& operator=(proxy const&) = default;
      public:
        data* operator->() { return d_; }
      };
    public:
      proxy operator->() {
        proxy ret(&stat);
        return ret;
      }
};


int main()
{
  iterator i;
  i->a = 3;

  // All the following will not compile
  // iterator::proxy p = i.operator->();
  // auto p = i.operator->();
  // auto p{i.operator->()};
}
```

---

Upon further review of my suggested solution, I realized that it's not quite as fool-proof as I thought. One cannot create an object of the proxy class outside the scope of `iterator`, but one can still bind a reference to it:

```
auto &&r = i.operator->();
auto *d  = r.operator->();
```

Thus allowing to apply `operator->()` again.

The immediate solution is to qualify the operator of the proxy object, and make it applicable only to rvalues. Like so for my live example:

```
data* operator->() && { return d_; }
```

This will cause the two lines above to emit an error again, while the proper use of the iterator still works. Unfortunately, this still doesn't protect the API from abuse, due to the availability of casting, mainly:

```
auto &&r = i.operator->();
auto *d  = std::move(r).operator->();
```

Which is a death blow to the whole endeavor. There is no preventing this.

So in conclusion, there is no protection from a direction call to `operator->` on the iterator object. At the most, we can only make the API really hard to use incorrectly, while the correct usage remains easy.

If creation of `row_view` copies is expansive, this may be good enough. But that is for you to consider.

Another point for consideration, which I haven't touched on in this answer, is that the proxy could be used to implement copy on write. But that class could be just as vulnerable as the proxy in my answer, unless great care is taken and fairly conservative design is used.

Comment: Just so I get this right: calling `operator->` without discarding the return value would result in a compiler error since the return type (`row_proxy`) is private?

Comment: @Jonas - Not just. Making the return type private only prevents one "attack". Hiding the constructor and assignment operator prevent capturing it with type deduction `auto p = ...`.

Comment: Thanks for detailing and the additional info. I suppose, I'm happy with your answer and will probably accept soon. It's not quite what I expected. Working around the problem and ensuring `operator->` cannot be used "maliciously" (to varying degrees of success) didn't even occur to me. My original question was aiming more at what would be considered idiomatic.

Comment: Even in the original version 1, I think it would be pretty hard to abuse this function by accident, since `operator->` has to be called by full name explicitly which I don't think anybody in their right mind would prefer over just using `operator*`. When there is malicious intent, I suppose there is always some way to cast the heck out of anything.

Comment: I didn't know that is was possible to rvalue-qualify member functions. That's pretty cool, although I'm struggling to come up with another scenario where that would be useful. Anyway, much appreciated.

Comment: @Jonas - Well, if you want idiomatic code, nothing beats the arrow operator. I'd go so far as to say that it's even expected of a pointer-like class to support it, along with `operator*`. As for the value-category qualification on members, yeah I didn't use it much either until answering your question, so thank you for that. You can l-value qualify as well. I, like you, am struggling to find a use case myself, at the moment.

Comment: In case you're interested, `std::optional` seems to be a fitting example for ref-qualification: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/ref-qualifiers/#ampshare=https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/ref-qualifiers/

Comment: @Jonas - Neat. I never delved into the details of `optional`'s implementation, but it makes perfect sense.

Comment: I probably would not bother with all this, just making a note in the documentation for `operator->` that saving the result in unusual ways is not recommended. As they say, in C++ you can often protect against Murphy but not Machiavelli.